# Let n and k be positive integers. If n ≥ (k + 1), then n! + (k + 1) is a composite number

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I've been having trouble with finding the proof for this question. Can anybody explain the solution to me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n\geq k+1$ then one of the factors of $n!$ is obviously going to be $k+1$ since the factorial of $n$ is the product of all natural numbers less than or equal to $n$, thus you can always factor out $k+1$ in $n!+k+1$ if $n\geq k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try expressing $n!+(k+1)$ as $(k+1)N$ where $N$ is a natural number greater than $1$. That should be pretty simple as $n\geq (k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$n!$ is a multiple of $k+1$ since $k+1$ is one of the factors involved. Now, if you add $k+1$ to a multiple of $k+1$, you obtain another multiple of $k+1$.